# Convert XML document to HTML and set <head>

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, browser

I have an xml document loaded into the browser. I need to use it as a template to generate and display as an html page in its place, with all the work happening in JavaScript on the client.

I've got it mostly done:

- The xml document loads a JavaScript file.
- The JavaScript reads the document and generates the html document that I want to display.
- The JavaScript replaces the document's innerHTML with the new html document.

The one thing that I'm missing is that I'd like to also supply the head of the new document.

I can create the head's content, of course. But, I cannot find any way to set it back into the browser's document.  All my obvious attempts fail, hitting read-only elements of the document, or operations that are not supported on non-HTML documents.

Is there any way to do this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Alternative question: Even if this is really impossible, maybe it doesn't matter. Possibly I can use my JavaScript to accomplish everything that might be controlled by the head (e.g., viewport settings). After all, the JavaScript knows the full display environment and can make all needed decisions. Is this a sane approach, or will it lead to thousands of lines code to handle browser-specific or device-specific special cases?

*Edited - added the following:*

I think the real question is broader: The browser (at least Chrome and Chromium) seems to make a sharp distinction between pages loaded as .xml and pages loaded as .html.  I'm trying to bend these rules: I load a page as .xml, but then I use JavaScript to change it into .html.

But, the browser still wants to view the page as .xml. This manifests in many ways: I can't add a `<head>`; I can't load CSS into the page; formatting tags are not interpreted as html; etc.

How can I convince the browser that my page is now bona fide html?

Comment: have you considered XSLT - as you've shown no code as such, it's just a suggestion

Comment: The overall goal here is to create a JavaScript replacement for much of XSLT, so I'd prefer a pure JavaScript solution. But, if that's impossible, then I'm open to all solutions.

Comment: Also, I just gave a quick look, and it's not clear to me that XSLT can change the document head.  Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't used xslt in many years - I just know that I used xslt to create a (full) HTML document from XML - so that would include the `<head>` - not really sure what "read only" bits you're talking about, nor what you are trying to do with the HTML you produce

Comment: `document.head` is read-only so the most naive approach failed. document.write also fails because the browser opened the original file as xml, and only supports write on html docs.

Big picture is that I want a single xml file to be renderable as text, pdf, or html, from node, and also to be viewable in the browser as the rendered html. So, the XSLT would need to convert the structure (easy) and then get it back into the browser's dom (easy except for the head).

Comment: I would suggest using a server-side solution here. Add code to read a request for "filename.xml?output=html", transform the XML to HTML using XSLT (with the `head`), then serve it to the browser.

Comment: Load the empty page as html and use REST to get the XML and JavaScript to draw the page. That is done all the time in applications

Comment: Looks like I'm going to wind up doing that. It fails to meet one of the project goals, but the stakeholders have agreed that it is good enough, rather than tilt at windmills. Thanks.